# Multiple instances of the same process is picking up the same message from a oracle queue

Tags: oracle, queue

DAQS is a custom process which consumes messages from oracle queue costedeventqueuetail. There will be multiple instances of DAQS running polling the same queue.
Our expectation is that once the message is processed by DAQS, it should be deleted and no other instance should pick up the same message from queue. But, it is not working in some environments though the oracle version is same.

Below is the logic to read queue message.

```
 while(iContinueFlag  == TRUE)
     {
         strMesg = Cdatabase::instance()->readQueueMessage(iMlen,sMsgQueueName);
         mPrsr.processMessage(msg,iRateStatus,iDomainGroupID,iCopyNumber);
        if (strMesg)
            {
               delete[] strMesg; strMesg = NULL;
                                            }
                if( !messageFromQueue->isNull())
                {
                   messageFromQueue->setNull();
                }
            }

unsigned char * Cdatabase::readQueueMessage(int &iMlen,char* sMsgQName) 
          throw(SQLException)
    {
       Consumer cons(conn);
       cons.setConsumerName("DAQS");
       cons.setPositionOfMessage(Consumer::DEQ_FIRST_MSG);
       cons.setDequeueMode(Consumer::DEQ_REMOVE);
       cons.setWaitTime(Consumer::DEQ_NO_WAIT);

       cons.setQueueName(sMsgQName);
       *messageFromQueue = cons.receive(Message::RAW);
       Bytes msgByte = messageFromQueue->getBytes();
       iMlen = msgByte.length();
       unsigned char* mesg = new unsigned char [iMlen];
       memset (mesg, 0, iMlen);
       msgByte.getBytes(mesg, iMlen, 0, 0);
       return mesg;
}
```

We have created queue and subscriber using the below logic.

```
       DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(queue_table        => ‘COSTEDEVENTQUEUETAIL’,
                                     multiple_consumers => TRUE,
                                     queue_payload_type => 'RAW',
                                     compatible         => '8.1.3',
                                     sort_list          => 'PRIORITY,ENQ_TIME');

       dbms_aqadm.create_queue(queue_name     => ‘COSTEDEVENTQUEUETAIL’,
                               queue_table    => ‘COSTEDEVENTQUEUETAIL’,
                               retention_time => 0);

       dbms_aqadm.start_queue(queue_name => ‘COSTEDEVENTQUEUETAIL’);

      Q_SUBSC := SYS.AQ$_AGENT('DAQS', NULL, NULL);
      DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(
      'COSTEDEVENTQUEUETAIL',--QUEUE_NAME     IN VARCHAR2,
      Q_SUBSC,--SUBSCRIBER     IN SYS.AQ$_AGENT,
      NULL,--RULE           IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
      NULL,--TRANSFORMATION IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
      FALSE,--QUEUE_TO_QUEUE IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
      DBMS_AQADM.PERSISTENT--DELIVERY_MODE  IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT DBMS_AQADM.PERSISTENT
      );
```

Could some one please let me know what can be done to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.
G. Jayasree

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have edited your question so the code can be read without scrolling. For future reference please take the time to layout out your code so it can be read on this site. You're more likely to get a timely and helpful response if your question is easy to read.

Comment: Having said which, questions along the line of "this code works correctly in some environments but not in others" are virtually impossible for us to answer. We don't know your environments, we don't know how they differ.

Comment: Thanks much for editing it. I have posted it in hurry to get an answer.

Comment: We have a reported issue of Bug 27122131 - DEQUEUE BY CONDITION CAUSING DUPLICATE MESSAGES TO BE DEQUEUED.
It is observed that dequeue log functionality(optimal dequeue) introduced in 11.2 can cause this problem due to redundant message locking in memory and on disk. 

As a workaround you can restore the dequeue behaviour to pre-11.2 queue by enabling following event.
conn /as sysdba 

alter system set events '10852 trace name context forever, level 16384'; 

We have set the above and restarted the process. We are not seeing this issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

We have got the below reply from oracle support.

We have a reported issue of Bug 27122131 - DEQUEUE BY CONDITION CAUSING DUPLICATE MESSAGES TO BE DEQUEUED. It is observed that dequeue log functionality(optimal dequeue) introduced in 11.2 can cause this problem due to redundant message locking in memory and on disk.

As a workaround you can restore the dequeue behaviour to pre-11.2 queue by enabling following event.

```
conn /as sysdba 
alter system set events '10852 trace name context forever, level 16384';**
```

We have set the above and restarted the multiple instances of the process. We are not seeing this issue anymore.